# install MySQL JDBC driver msi

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have downloaded the JDBC driver for MySQL "mysql-connector-java-gpl-5.1.26.msi" from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/. But i can't figure out how to use it. The documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-binary-installation.html says it is a zip file which has the required jar file. But what i got is a .msi file. When i execute the msi file it just starts installing and disappears. Any ideas how i can get the jar file from the msi?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The msi installation places the file at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar`.

You can also download the platform independent zip file and extract the jar file whereever you want.

Comment: I found the jar under C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 5.1.26\ folder. Downloading the platform independent zip also worked.

Comment: Yep same here, make sure to check that X86 folder!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the installer. use the drop down menu under Select Platform:, and select Platform Independent. If you don't know how to use a TAR archive, download the zip file, unzip and there is the .bin file. For eclipse, drop this into the project directory, find the file, right click, and build path. This method may cause issues if you download a java update.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly used it from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar after installing the msi. If you are using IDE like Netbeans and Eclipse just go to your project then right click the Libraries folder then click add jar option then go the mysql connector directory and then select the mysql connector jar file.